# Lower RAM consumption for a transformation of a transition matrix

Tags: r, matrix, transform

I've written the following two functions, that take as input a transition matrix and which nodes should be at absorbing states and transforms it.

The first function `set.absorbing.states()` has 3 arguments. `tm` is the initial transition matrix, the second one `inn` is one specified innitial node, while the third one `soi` is the set of interest. By 'set of interest', I mean a set of nodes in that matrix that must been set as absorbing states. Such an initial matrix is the following:

```
tm <- read.table(row.names=1, header=FALSE, text="
A 0.2 0.3 0.1 0.2 0.1 0.1 
B 0.3 0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2 0.1
C 0 0.2 0.4 0.1 0.2 0.1 
D 0.2 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.1 0.1
E 0.2 0.2 0.1 0.2 0.1 0.2
F 0.3 0.2 0.4 0.1 0 0")

colnames(tm) <- row.names(tm)
```

As you can see there are no absorbing states in that matrix. Let's say for example that we want to set as absorbing states the `A` and `E` and a randomly selected initial node `B`.

By executing the first function `tm1 <- set.absorbing.states( tm , "B", c("A","E"))` we are getting back a matrix that the absorbing states have been setted:

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F
A 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
B 0.3 0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2 0.1
C 0.0 0.2 0.4 0.1 0.2 0.1
D 0.2 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.1 0.1
E 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0
F 0.3 0.2 0.4 0.1 0.0 0.0
```

As you can see, `A` and `E` have been changed into absorbing states.

The next step is to transform that matrix into a way that all absorbing state nodes (both rows and columns) go to the end. So by running `ptm <- transform.tm( tm1, c("A","E") )` we get back a matrix that looks like:

```
    B   C   D   F   A   E
B 0.1 0.1 0.2 0.1 0.3 0.2
C 0.2 0.4 0.1 0.1 0.0 0.2
D 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.1 0.2 0.1
F 0.2 0.4 0.1 0.0 0.3 0.0
A 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0
E 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
```

You can see now clearly that `A` and `E` nodes went to the end of that matrix.

Here follows the function I'm using.

```
set.absorbing.states <- function ( tm, inn, soi )
{
  set <- which( row.names(tm) %in% soi )
  set <- set[which( set != inn )]
  for (i in set )
    tm[i,] <- 0
  for (i in set)
    tm[i,i] <- 1
  tm
}

transform.tm <- function ( tm, soi )
{
  end_sets <- which(row.names(tm) %in% soi)
  ptm <- rbind( cbind(tm[-end_sets, -end_sets], tm[-end_sets, end_sets]) , cbind(tm[end_sets, -end_sets], tm[end_sets, end_sets]) )
  ptm
}
```

The thing now is that with such small matrices, everything is working properly. But I tried to use a big matrix (20.000*20.000) and it needed 32GB RAM to execute the second function.

So is there any way to execute this in more resource efficient way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use indexing will significantly reduce the number of copies that your transformation function is creating (via `rbind` and `cbind`). It is probably a bit simpler conceptually (conditional on a solid understanding of indexing with `[`).

```
transform.tm1 <- function ( tm, soi ) {
  newOrder <- c(setdiff(row.names(tm), soi), soi)
  tm[newOrder, newOrder]
}
```

Here, `setdiff` is used to pull the non matching names and put them at the front a the vector. Then, simply reorder the matrix via row/column names.

This returns

```
transform.tm1(tm1, c("A", "E"))
    B   C   D   F   A   E
B 0.1 0.1 0.2 0.1 0.3 0.2
C 0.2 0.4 0.1 0.1 0.0 0.2
D 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.1 0.2 0.1
F 0.2 0.4 0.1 0.0 0.3 0.0
A 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0
E 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
```

check that they return the same results

```
identical(transform.tm(tm1, c("A", "E")), transform.tm1(tm1, c("A", "E")))
[1] TRUE
```